# aget vs axel vs aria2

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

I'm looking for a multi-threaded (fast) alternative to wget which can download large files. The choices seem to be aget, axel and aria2. I'm familiar with axel (thanks to apt-fast). Which is the best alternative?

EDIT (based on scott's suggestion):
What I was looking for was a download accelerator that could download large files (videos, tar files). I had not used command line accelerators before and it seemed there were quite few options out there. I was evaluating these, and wanted to seek opinion of anyone who has used one of these.

My Answer: I have installed both arai2 (to download torrent files) and axel to download smaller files like pdf, zip files.

Comment: -1 as this question is very subjective (which one is best, with no stated purpose). Voting to close as [not constructive](http://askubuntu.com/faq#close).

Comment: As I mentioned the purpose is to download large file in a multithreaded way and there are 3 options. i wanted opinions on what others think is the best tool.
Anyway what i've concluded is aria2 is the tool if you want torrent  and other protocols. otherwise aget/axel are equally good for downloading http links/files

Comment: Here is an interesting links, looks like axel cannot handle really large files (4GB). This is the kind of info I was looking for. http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-day-at-the-races-aria2-vs-axel/

Comment: You might want to consider editing your original question to include some definition of what criteria you deem to be "best". Your comments have shown a bit of the type of info you're looking for, since your question is so vague. Without your comments, no one reading your question would know how to answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott, 
I have edited my question based on your suggestion. Now that the question is clear(er). Do you have an opinion on what the best download tool is? What do you use (if any) and why?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've removed my down vote. As to your specific question, I have no experience with the programs you mentioned. `wget` meets my needs.